# If $\{f_n\}\subset L^+, f_n$ decreases pointwise to $f,$ and $\int f_1<\infty,$ then $\int f=\lim\int f_n$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

If $\{f_n\}\subset L^+, f_n$ decreases pointwise to $f,$ and $\int f_1<\infty,$ then $\int f=\lim\int f_n.$

I am not really sure why we need the integration of f1 finite. I am trying to use Monotone Convergent Theorem, but in this one, fn is decreasing though.

Comment: $f_n$ could be decreasing pointwise but still integrate to infinity, so $f_1$ integrating to a number ensures all $f_n$ integrate to a finite value.

Answer (score 3):

Each $f_{n}$ is dominated by $f_{1}\in L^{1}$, so apply the dominated convergence theorem

Answer (score 0):

One counterexample is the following. Let $f_n (x) = \frac{e^x}{n}>0$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n \text{ d}x =+\infty$. In particular, $f_1$ is not an $L^1$ function.

Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise and monotonically but,

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n \text{ d}x = +\infty  \neq 0 =\int_\mathbb{R} 0 \text{ d}x $